# use haml template in Sinatra framework

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How to create a page using Sinatra which will use my prepared `index.html.haml` template.

Let's say i have following code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sass'
require 'haml'

get '/' do
  haml :index ???
end
```

my `index.html.haml` file is located in `/sinatraapp/haml/index.html.haml`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell `sinatra` where your views are located - [see this](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__view_template_directory)

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sass'
require 'haml'

set :views, "path/to/your/haml/dir"

get '/' do
  haml :index
end
```

Comment: Another question, how to attach my sas stylesheets to my sinatra app?
i put the following code to my index.html:
%link(rel="stylesheet" href="sass/styles.scss")  
and get('/sass/styles.scss') { scss :styles } but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: It's hard to tell in the comments. I would post another question and you will probably get some additional help. If I have time, I will try to answer.